# Function to wrap a value to array if it is not and output correct type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function to wrap a value to array if it is not an array

```
export function asArray<T extends Array<any>>(value: T): T
export function asArray<T>(value: T): T[]
export function asArray(value: any) {
  return Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]
}
```

But it doesn't work when the type of value is union type

```
type A = { a: 1 } | { a: 1 }[]

const fn = (v: A) => {
  const b = asArray(v)
  return b[0].a
}
```

it throws

```
Property 'a' does not exist on type 'A'.
  Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ a: 1; }[]'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your union type is not an array, so it is using the second declaration:

```js
function asArray<{ a: number } | { a: number }[]>(value: T): Array<{ a: number } | { a: number }[]>
```

So, for the compiler, your `b[0]` can either be a { a: number } or an array of it. It therefore cannot be sure that there is a `a` property in it.

You would better define your function as:

```js
export function asArray<T>(value: T | T[]): T[] {
  return ([] as T[]).concat(value)
}
```

This would even not require an overload.

Comment: `[].concat(value)` will return a new array rather than `value` even if `value` is an array.

Comment: @acrazing: right, and it may be a performance issue. If so, the conditional expression posted by OP should be preferred.